# Retrieve image from content, assign it as a featured, and then remove it from the content

Tags: images, content

I am trying to grab the first image from the content and use as featured image, then remove the that image from the content.

I found the plugin get the image, but it doesn't save image on the post, at least on 3.5.1 wp

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing? Why not just insert the featured image properly? Why add it to the post only to pull it back out?

Comment: sorry, my bad, the question was really impossible to be understood! the fact is that I am in the process of migrating content from joomla 2 wordpress and in wordpress i am using the featured image in order to display the post in a nicer way. in joomla the image was inside the content as first item, so i am trying to reassign the image of joomla as feat img in wp :)